# Using Sendgrid and Azure : 550, b'Unauthenticated senders not allowed'

Tags: python, django, azure, email, sendgrid

I am trying to send a password reset email to users, via an App we are developping with Django.
When trying the App locally, the user can select to reset a pwd if forgotten , input his email into a field and submit, in order to receive an email. The sender email is a business email address.
Checking into Sendgrid, I can see the activity log that the email has been processed and delivered. So it seems working.

However, when trying to do the same passing via Github, Azure, on https://XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/en/password_reset/, I get the following :

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /en/password_reset/
(550, b'Unauthenticated senders not allowed', 'nicolas@XXXXX.com')
```

in the log I get the following as well:

```
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
```

Is there something I am missing with Azure, another key to include. I read through many similar issues, but could not find a suitable response to my problem. The fact `Sendgrid` works locally but not with Azure make me think I am missing a connection at that level. Otherwise, All other aspects of the App works when hosting it on Azure..

Below are the codes I am using:

**in settings.py**

```
import os

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net']

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' #Exactly that

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY 

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'nicolas@XXXXX.com'
```

**in views :**

```
from django.core import mail

from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from django.utils.html import strip_tags

def send_password_reset_email(request):

    subject = 'email reset'

    html_message = render_to_string('password_reset_email.html', {'context': 'values'})
    plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)

    from_email = 'nicolas@XXXXX.com'

    form = (request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        data = form.cleaned_data

        to=data.get("email")
    

    mail.send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, [to], html_message=html_message,fail_silently=False)
```

**in url.py:**

```
urlpatterns=[
    url('', views.send_password_reset_email)
]
```

merci
Nicolas

Comment: did you check the sendgrid logs within sendgrid account ? there may be cases where the ip addresses from where the email originates can be blacklisted by spamhaus and that is causing the mails to fail. https://sendgrid.com/blog/avoiding-email-blacklists/

Comment: Do you mean the Activity log ? if yes, there is no email being sent. I can see on the activity log  the emails sent and delivered if I use the app from my local server. However, if I use the app from Azure, there is no new activity listed. I get this message: 550, b'Unauthenticated senders not allowed'

Comment: Are you using the same from email when testing locally and from Azure?

Comment: Yes, I am, this is why I do not understand why it works when testing locally and not from Azure.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved: If SendGrid works locally, but not on Azure:

In Azure, select ‘configuration', 'Application settings', 'new application settings' and then, as per below, using the correct API name made it work.

In SendGrid, I had named my API key ‘test’, and thought in Azure I should name it the same. However, I should have named it the same as in my code:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY
```

Not obvious at first.